# Strange regular expression string

Tags: regex, emacs

When I learn GNU Emacs Lisp, I get very confused about the code.

```
(looking-back "\\s)" 1)
```

I don't know what the `\\s)` stand for?I know it can mach the character `)`, and I want to know the rule of the matching string. Why not use the regular expression?

Answer (score 2):

"*I don't know what the `\\s)` stand for? I know it can mach the character `)`, and I want to know the rule of the matching string.*"

`\s)` matches one occurrence of a character with syntax class "close parenthesis".

See the Elisp manual, node [Syntax Class Table](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html).

> Open parenthesis characters: `(`
>
> Close parenthesis characters: `)`
>
> Characters used in dissimilar pairs to surround sentences or
>        expressions.  Such a grouping is begun with an open parenthesis
>        character and terminated with a close.  Each open parenthesis
>        character matches a particular close parenthesis character, and
>        vice versa.  Normally, Emacs indicates momentarily the matching
>        open parenthesis when you insert a close parenthesis.  *Note
>        Blinking::.
>
> In human languages, and in C code, the parenthesis pairs are `()`,
>        `[]`, and `{}`.  In Emacs Lisp, the delimiters for lists and
>        vectors (`()` and `[]`) are classified as parenthesis characters.

Comment: To add to the above answer, in a string, `\ ` is a special character, so needs to be escaped as `\\ `. So after string processing, `"\s"` becomes `\s` which is an Emacs extension to regular expressions to handle a commonly encountered case in parsing programming languages (for syntax highlighting etc). [markdown also needs special treatment of `\ ` in some cases]

Comment: The Emacs Lisp pass the "\\s" to the C program to match the string?Thanks, I get it.